# Merge Two files of columns but insert columns of second file into columns of first file

Tags: linux, unix, join, merge, multiple-columns

Assume two files with same amount of columns.

```
file_A:

1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

and

```
file_B:

A B C D E
A B C D E
A B C D E
A B C D E
A B C D E
```

I want to merge two files in order like

```
file_C:

1 A 2 B 3 C 4 D 5 E
1 A 2 B 3 C 4 D 5 E
1 A 2 B 3 C 4 D 5 E
1 A 2 B 3 C 4 D 5 E
1 A 2 B 3 C 4 D 5 E
```

I have found a solution in the community like this

```
paste file_A file_B | awk '{print $1,$6,$2,$7,$3,$8,$4,$9,$5,$10}'
```

But considering amount of columns is like 100 for each file or not constant, I want to know if there is a better method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop in `awk`, for example

```
paste file_A file_B | awk '{ 
    half = NF/2; 
    for(i = 1; i < half; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s ", $i, $(i+half));
    }
    printf("%s %s\n", $half, $NF);
}'
```

or

```
paste file_A file_B | awk '{ 
    i = 1; j = NF/2 + 1;
    while(j < NF)
    {
        printf("%s %s ", $i, $j);
        i++; j++;
    }
    printf("%s %s\n", $i, $j);
}'
```

The code assumes that the number of columns in `awk`'s input is even.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner after `paste` to print alternating columns:

```
paste file_A file_B | perl -F'\t' -lane 'print join "\t", @F[ map { ( $_, $_ + ( @F/2 ) ) } 0 .. ( $#F - 1 ) /  2 ];'
```

Example:

Create tab-delimited input files:

```
perl -le 'print join "\t", 1..5 for 1..2;' > file_A
perl -le 'print join "\t", "A".."E" for 1..2;' > file_B
head file_A file_B
```

Prints:

```
==> file_A <==
1       2       3       4       5
1       2       3       4       5

==> file_B <==
A       B       C       D       E
A       B       C       D       E
```

Paste files side by side, also tab-delimited:

```
paste file_A file_B | perl -F'\t' -lane 'print join "\t", @F[ map { ( $_, $_ + ( @F/2 ) ) } 0 .. ( $#F - 1 ) /  2 ];'
```

Prints:

```
1       A       2       B       3       C       4       D       5       E
1       A       2       B       3       C       4       D       5       E
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'/\t/'` : Split into `@F` on TAB, rather than on whitespace.

`$#F` : last index of the array `@F` with the input fields, split on tab.
`0 .. ( $#F - 1 ) /  2` : array of **indexes** of the array `@F`, from the start (0) to half of the array. These are all indexes that correspond to `file_A`.
`map { ( $_, $_ + ( @F/2 ) ) } 0 .. ( $#F - 1 ) /  2` : `map` takes the above array of indexes from 0 to half of the length of `@F`, and returns a new array, with twice the number of elements. Its elements alternate: (a) the index corresponding to `file_A` (`$_`) and (b) that index plus half the length of the array (`$_ + ( @F/2 )`), which is the corresponding index from `file_B`.
`@F[ map { ( $_, $_ + ( @F/2 ) ) } 0 .. ( $#F - 1 ) /  2 ]` : a slice of array `@F` with the specified indexes, namely alternating fields from `file_A` and `file_B`.

**SEE ALSO:**

[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perldata`: Slices](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)

Answer (score 1):

With one awk script parsing the files:

```
FNR==NR {
    rec[NR] = $0
    next
}

{
    split(rec[FNR], fields)
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i = fields[i] FS $i
    print
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f tst.awk file_A file_B
```